# Errors with Tableau Extract Creation from Spark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

As per the Git hub project : [werneckpaiva/spark-to-tableau](https://github.com/werneckpaiva/spark-to-tableau)

I have setup Tableau-SDK in Windows OS in my local system. I am able to create the Tableau Extracts from the Spark Dataframe for up to 10 tables when it is trying to create an extract for the 11th table always I'm getting below specified error. If I re-execute with the next set of 10 tables it is working good but always maximum of 10 extracts it is creating.

Is there any limitation that maximum of 10 extracts(.tde) can be created and do we need to set any property to fix this?

Configuration Details :

- Spark : 1.6.2
- Scala : 2.10.6
- werneckpaiva.spark-to-tableau.0-1-0.jar
- jna-3.5.1.jar
- tableau-extract-9.1.0.jar
- tableau-server-9.1.0.jar
- tableau-common-9.1.0.jar

**Error Details:**

```
com.tableausoftware.TableauException: Unknown error 
at com.tableausoftware.extract.ExtractAPI.initialize(Unknown Source)
at tableau.TableauDataFrameImplicity.tableau$TableauDataFrameImplicity$$createTableauTable(TableauDataFrame.scala:65)
at tableau.TableauDataFrameImplicity$$anonfun$saveToTableau$1.apply(TableauDataFrame.scala:24)
at tableau.TableauDataFrameImplicity$$anonfun$saveToTableau$1.apply(TableauDataFrame.scala:22)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We need to create extracts for 30+ tables, any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kasi, this is odd. I'm a contributor to the project and we use it to generate many extracts daily. Saldy, the Tableau SDK message doesn't really help. Did you find a solution in the meantime?